# SSL handshake with intermediate certificate

Tags: ssl

During SSL handshake, the browser downloads any intermediate certificate from the host web server using the URL provided if needed. I believe browser comes with the pre-installed certificates from public CAs having only the public key of the root certificate.

1) When calling a https url using a standalone java program [https://xyz.com  ..which is using Verisign certificate], i do not need to add that Certificate to any truststore since its root public is already available in jdk's cacerts truststore file. Is this correct statement?

2) When i run the same program from application server, it requires to add all the intermediate certificate to server truststore individually. Why this works in different way.

Answer (score 1):

If the trust chain for the servers certificate is: root-intermediate#1-intermediate#2-server and the client (browser) has root as trusted CA in its CA store, it needs a way to verify the servers certificate by checking the complete chain up to the root. And because the client usually has no knowledge of the intermediate CAs the server needs to provide them.

Sometimes it seems to work w/o providing these intermediate CAs. First, the browsers usually cache the intermediate CAs they got and thus if intermediate#2 is the same as already seen by another server the verification will succeed, but only for the clients who visited the other server before :(

Another way is to provide a URL inside a certificate, where the issuer certificate can be downloaded, e.g. server could provide a link to the certificate for intermediate#2, intermediate#2 could provide a link to intermediate#1. In this case the client could download the missing certificates. But, this features is not universally adopted, e.g. some browsers might provide it but SSL libraries outside of the browsers usually don't.